# Keras prediction returns the same results each time

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm new in Keras. Just started locally an example taken from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-deep-learning-model-using-keras-1548ca149d37). The example data works fine. Then I modified the code a little bit to adapt to my data (in my data file result column goes first). Then when I run again and try to predict inputs, it always returns the same result for each input row - `[1. 0.], [1. 0.] ...`. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.utils import to_categorical

#read in training data
train_df_2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/my_user/python-workspace/Deep-Learning-in-Keras-Tutorial/data/my_data.csv')

#view data structure
train_df_2.head()

#create a dataframe with all training data except the target column
train_X_2 = train_df_2.drop(columns=['result'])

target = train_df_2[['result']]

#check that the target variable has been removed
train_X_2.head()

#one-hot encode target column
train_y_2 = to_categorical(train_df_2.result)

#create model
model_2 = Sequential()

#get number of columns in training data
n_cols_2 = train_X_2.shape[1]

#add layers to model
model_2.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols_2,)))
model_2.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
# model_2.add(Dense(10, input_dim=n_cols_2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
# model_2.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
# model_2.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model_2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#set early stopping monitor so the model stops training when it won't improve anymore
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)

#train model
model_2.fit(train_X_2, train_y_2, epochs=30, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])

p = model_2.predict(train_X_2, verbose=0, batch_size=1)
print(p)
```

Example of my input data:

```
result,i1,i2,i3,i4
0,1770,2390,1750,1816
1,1675,2540,2029,1940
1,1770,2384,1765,1770
0,1690,2485,2075,1900
0,1680,2465,2050,1920
0,1770,2395,1744,1795
1,1675,2490,2050,1915
0,1768,2400,1740,1790
0,1675,2525,2050,1910 
.... (total 2312 rows)
```

Why does it always return the same result `[1. 0.]` for each row? I expected at least one row of `[0. 1.]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think the model is overfitting as the data for your class 0 is more than that of class of 1 ? can you please give us the numbers of data for each class ?

Comment: I think you're using a too much powerful model to predict the result considering you only have 4 columns. You should try fitting a simple logistic regression instead. NN are great when you have a high complexity in your data.

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain it almost 50/50 for 0/1

Comment: You can use binary output format if `result` only has 2 values: 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not normalized the input data. Therefore it would hinder the training process and disrupt gradient updates and your model may learn nothing. Try normalizing it using something like [`sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). Or alternatively you can do it manually:

```
mean = train_X_2.mean(axis=0)
train_X_2 -= mean
std = train_X_2.std(axis=0)
train_X_2 /= std
```

Comment: Thank you! now results changed a little bit. Now it looks like [[0.4751541  0.5248459 ]
 [0.44454956 0.55545044]
 [0.47325155 0.5267484 ]] - first column always less that second. So, I need to play with data scaling? Should it always be < 1?

Comment: @CatH Yes, the values are usually normalized to a small range such as [0,1] or [-1, 1]. What is the accuracy of the model in training phase?

Comment: actually, I don't know... how can I set accuracy?

Comment: @CatH You have set `metrics=['accuracy']` so accuracy must be shown in the training progress bar?! It is written as `acc: xxxx`.

Comment: yes, I have this in output like acc: 0.5248. is it a good coefficient?

Comment: @CatH That's not a coefficient. It is the accuracy of the model. It means 52% of the samples has been classified correctly. And this is not good!

Comment: do you have any advice how to improve this?

Comment: @CatH Well, it is hard to say without knowing the problem and data. But you can increase the number of units/layers in your model so that to overfit on your training data. You can also gather more training data. Then you can combat overfiting using regularization methods. Just search underfiting and overfiting on a search engine and you would find lots of tutorials about them. Further, you can change the number of units in the last layer to 1 and use `sigmoid` as the its activation function and `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used your model with binary outcome on `iris` dataset (first 100 rows which have only 2 types in targets):

```
def getmodel(n_cols_2): 
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.utils import to_categorical
    #create model
    model_2 = Sequential()
    #add layers to model
    model_2.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols_2,)))
    model_2.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
    model_2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
    #compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
    model_2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model_2

from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
train_X_2 = iris.data[:100]
train_y_2 = iris.target[:100]
# print top 5 rows:
print(train_X_2[:5])
print(train_y_2[:5])
n_cols = iris.data.shape[1]
# get model: 
model = getmodel(n_cols)
# set early stopping monitor so the model stops training when it won't improve anymore
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)
#train model
model.fit(train_X_2, train_y_2, epochs=30, batch_size=10 , validation_split=0.2) # , callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])
# predict and print classes
p = model.predict_classes(train_X_2, verbose=0, batch_size=10)
print(p.ravel())
```

The output is perfect:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]]
[0 0 0 0 0]
Using TensorFlow backend.
Train on 80 samples, validate on 20 samples
Epoch 1/100
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7615 - acc: 0.3750 - val_loss: 0.4282 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/100
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 88us/step - loss: 0.6658 - acc: 0.3750 - val_loss: 0.4944 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 3/100
...
...
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Note that standardization has not been used here. Absence of standardization may affect prediction but cannot make neural network non-functional as was happening in your case.

Also note I used `sigmoid`, `binary_crossentropy` and `predict_classes`.

Generally, a conical shape is used, so your 2nd Dense layer may have only 12 neurons or so. Also, accuracy may improve by adding [Dropout](https://keras.io/layers/core/) layers after each Dense layer.

If you still get all 0 or 1, it may be that your data is quite random and not really predicting the target.